# Opencv, win 7, 64 bit

Tags: opencv

I have installed opencv 2.2 on win 7 64 and VS 2010 with 32bit option. Can I make it run for 64 bit also.
IS there any link to compile Opencv with win 7 64 and VS2008/2010. 
regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look on this unoffical python extensions library, there is some 64bit builts.

> http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv